# How to access to the vue store in the asyncData function of nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

in a component i want to acces to the store with the asyncData function like so :

```
asyncData({ app, params }) {
var url = `https://myapi/news/${app.$store.state.market}/detail/${params.id}`;
return app.$axios.get(url).then(response => {
  return { actu: response.data };
});
```

}

but i received "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

is there another to receive the state of the store here ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to get store from context. [Reference](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/)

```
asyncData({ app, params, store }) {
   var url = `https://myapi/news/${store.state.market}/detail/${params.id}`;
   return app.$axios.get(url).then(response => {
      return { actu: response.data };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

Store/index.js

```
...

state: {
  loadedPages: []
}
...
```

Page

```
async asyncData(context) {
...
console.log(context.store.state.loadedPages)
...

}
```